# How to update articles in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, edit, blogs

I made a blog using Django. I watched a lot of videos to make a function that the user can update/edit own articles. But I did not get it work. I'm new in Django, so if anyone can help me, I would be thankful.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Article
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import forms
#from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def article_list(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    paginator = Paginator(Article.objects.all().order_by('-date'), 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    index = items.number - 1
    max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
    page_range = paginator.page_range[0:max_index]

    return render(request, 'articles/article_list.html', {'articles':articles, 'items':items, 'page_range':page_range})

@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def article_details(request, slug):
    article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'articles/article_details.html', {'article':article})

@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def article_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateArticle(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('articles:list')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateArticle()
    return render(request, 'articles/article_create.html', {'form':form})

@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def article_edit(request, slug):
    article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = forms.CreateArticle(request.GET, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect('articles:list')
    return render(request, 'articles/article_edit.html', {'form':form})
```

I was trying to do the view in article_edit.

Here is the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

from .views import article_edit

app_name = 'articles'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.article_list, name="list"),
    url(r'^create/$', views.article_create, name="create"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.article_details, name="details"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', views.article_edit, name="edit"),
]
```

I would like to do it with url() just like the article_details above.

Here is the article_details.html which contains the edit button:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if article.author.id == user.id %}
    <nav class="UpdateArticle">
        <li><a href="{% url 'articles:edit' slug=article.slug %}" class="ArticleEdit">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'articles:delete' %}" class="ArticleDelete">Delete</a></li>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
<div class="article-details">
    <div class="article">
        <img src="{{ article.thumb.url }}"/>
        <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
        <div class="infos">
            <p>Director: {{ article.director }}</p>
            <p>Protagonist(s): {{ article.protagonist }}</p>
        </div>
        <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
        <p class="author">Created by <br>{{ article.author }}</p>
        <p>{{ article.date }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The delete function is not implemented yet. Now I am focusing on the edit.

And here is my article_edit.html:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="edit-article">
    <h2>Edit an article</h2>
    <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'articles:edit' slug=article.slug %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="/static/slugify.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the instance to the form:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def article_edit(request, slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateArticle(request.GET, request.FILES, instance=article)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('articles:list')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateArticle(instance=article)
    return render(request, 'articles/article_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

You probably also want to restrict access to the author, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def article_edit(request, slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug, author=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateArticle(request.GET, request.FILES, instance=article)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('articles:list')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateArticle(instance=article)
    return render(request, 'articles/article_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

However such views can be reduced to using a simple [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.url import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import UpdateView


class ArticleEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Article
    success_url = reverse_lazy('articles:list')
    form_class = forms.CreateArticle
```

and if we want to restrict access to only the author:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import UpdateView


class ArticleEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Article
    form_class = forms.CreateArticle
    success_url = reverse_lazy('articles:list')

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(author=self.request.user)
        )
```

or you can redirect it to the detail page of the edited article with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import UpdateView


class ArticleEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Article
    form_class = forms.CreateArticle

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(author=self.request.user)
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('articles:details', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `ArticleForm` instead of
> <s>`CreateArticle`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: @MailFun: you will need to use `ArticleEditView.as_view()` in the `urls.py`.

Comment: I have the following error: ImproperlyConfigured at /articles/the-avengers-endgame/edit/
Using ModelFormMixin (base class of ArticleEditView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.

Comment: @MailFun: I made a mistake, it is `form_class`, not `form`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsen: Thank you very much. I needed to rename my article_edit.html to article_form.html. Is it possible to leaves it article_edit.html or it is a naming convention for the UpdateView. However, now form is replicates the data. But when I click on the Update button it said:
ImproperlyConfigured at /articles/the-avengers-endgame/edit/

No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

Comment: @MailFun: ah yes, you need to add a `success_url` to specify where to redirect to. Apparently brain was offline at the time of writing :(.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsen: No problem at all. I was really lost with the edit functionality. You made this project nearly completed, so thank you for your time. As I said, I am really a newbie in Django. I tried to search this success_url thing to understand how to "build it up". I added `success_url = 'articles/article_details.html'`. But it's just appends after the current url like:127.0.0.1:8000/articles/the-avengers-endgame/edit/articles/article_details.html.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsen: I would like to redirect the user to the article's detail page what the user is edited. I tried something like the return render(request, 'articles/article_details.html', {'article':article})

Comment: @WillemVanOnsen: Now It's working. Thank you very much. Could you explain what reverse_lazy is doing? And I would like to implement the Delete fuctionality. Should I make a new question to that or is there a chat in StackOverflow? Or just cuntinue commenting?

Comment: @MailFun: it determines the path for a given view name (and parameters), so in this case what the path would be for the `details` view for that specific article. I think usually a new question is created for something that is another problem.